# Nested Resource in an admin Namespace form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

I'm not fully understanding how nested resources forms work.

I have a form to create new events in my admin namespace "helm"

Events belong to an activity.

My routes look like this

```
 namespace :helm do
    resources :providers,  :locations
    resources :events, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
    resources :activities do
      resources :events, only: [:new, :create]
    end
  end
```

my events#new action looks like this

```
def new      
  @activity = Activity.find(params[:activity_id])
  @event = @activity.events.build
  ...
```

and my form_for helper looks like this:

```
<%= form_for [:helm,  @event] do |f| %>
```

I'm getting the error

```
undefined method `helm_events_path'
```

presumably because i haven't managed to tell rails i want the form to be for the nested route:

```
new_helm_activity_event_path
```

Where have i gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to specify the activity in the form_for call.

```
<%= form_for [:helm, @activity, @event] do |f| %>
  # etc
<% end %>
```